# Is there a way to check only one checkbox from list in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I need a help. I'm doing a quiz and i have a list of answers with checkboxes. But I need to set that user can select only 1 checkbox from list and if he want to select second from the list in one answer, it would alert him that he cant do that. I already tried to change type of input to radio, but it isnt working well. Any solutions?

HTML:

```
<label v-for="answer in question.answers" class="answer" :class="{ 'answer-correct':answer.correct, 'answer-false':answer.false }">
                <input type="checkbox" data- :value="answer.id" v-model="answer.selected"> {{ answer.answer }}
            </label>
```

JS Submiting Quiz:

```
this.questions.forEach(question => 
        {
            question.answers.forEach(answer => 
            {
                answer.correct = question.correct.includes(answer.id);
                answer.false = question.false.includes(answer.id);

                if (((answer.correct = question.correct.includes(answer.id)) && (answer.selected == true)))
                {
                    this.points++;
                }
            });
        });
```

JS One question:

```
var questions = 
[
{
    question: "Kolik je 34+21?",
    answers: 
    [ 
        { id: 0, answer: "68", correct: false }, 
        { id: 1, answer: "53", correct: false }, 
        { id: 2, answer: "55", correct: false } 
    ],
    correct: [2],
    selected: [],
    false: [0, 1],
    answercorrect: [],
    answerfalse: [],
    answerfalse2: []
},
```

Comment: `<input type="radio"` should do it.

Comment: @MikeEason i wrote that i tried, but it is not working for me.

Comment: Radio buttons implementation is a little bit different than checkboxes, all buttons need to have the same `name` attribute, and the function that check value is usually on the parent element.

Comment: You can also use vuetify or other ui component library for vue. In vuetify you have v-radio that is easy to use